# Use GSP expression in CSS

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm using the https://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline for our project. Can I use GSP expressions in the CSS files? I need to create some of the CSS programatically so not all CSS is static.

I reference the CSS in my main.gsp layout with

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
```

and then created the following file:

```
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.gsp
```

But the file is not being references/included. I also tried

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application"/>
```

and

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application.gsp"/>
```

But they all don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Asset-Pipeline is a plugin used for managing and processing **static**
>   assets in Grails applications.

The easiest way to achieve "dynamic" CSSes is to override specified styles inline in your views.

Moreover you can always use preprocessors for generating sophisticated CSSes.